# How to find the path of a specific deep subdirectory with only the subdirectory's name?

Tags: python

I want to move a file into a subdirectory. The subdirectory is within several subdirectories. I have only the name of the parent directory and the name of the subdirectory that I want the file to go into. I do not know the subdirectories in-between the parent directory and destination subdirectory and need to find where that subdirectory is with its absolute path so I can then move the file into that subdirectory.

I have tried os.path.isdir() and os.path.exists() to search for my subdirectory, but the search does not seem to search into all subdirectories.

```
    import os

def find_dir(name, start):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
        for d in dirs:
            if d == name:
                return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, d))

subdir_name = 'Shanahan,Austin-1234'
starting_dir = r'C:\Users\austin.shanahan\Desktop\PeopleTest'

print(find_dir(subdir_name, starting_dir))   # returns "None"
```

***There is a subdirectory called Shanahan,Austin-1234 deep in the directory PeopleTest. There are two subdirectories in-between the directory PeopleTest and the subdirectory Shanahan,Austin-1234.  I need to find Shanahan,Austin-1234 within all of that and output the absolute path.

Comment: You need to recursively search the subdirectories yourself until either the item searched is found or there are no subdirectories to search.

Comment: what OS are you running if debian you can use the `call("find <your/starting/directory> filename_you_are_searching.for")` and then parse the result

Comment: @ThunderHorn Given that Python is a cross-platform language, it wouldn't make sense to use platform-specific code for a non-platform-specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

layout:

```
.
  -> dir1
         -> dir2
                -> first.last-0000
```

Code:

```
import os

def find_dir(name, start):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start):
        for d in dirs:
            if d == name:
                return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, d))

subdir_name = 'first.last-0000'
starting_dir = 'C:/users/me/desktop/peopleTest'

print(find_dir(subdir_name, starting_dir))
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\peopleTest\dir1\dir2\first.last-0000
```

Comment: And possibly `break` after finding the file, if that's desired :)

Comment: @AKX I'd normally do it in a function, so a return instead of a print.

Comment: Sure. Point being it's no use walking through the rest of the tree.

Comment: @tgikal - yes that's the logic i'm looking for. my code doesn't output a result though. I'll edit my question to show what I have at this point

Comment: @austin The latest edit should work for that layout. (side note `dir` is a python keyword and should be avoided.)

Comment: @tgikal thanks for that side note. I have used your bit of code but it returns "None" for some reason. Could this be because the code is searching for d in dirs but not in subdirs? That is possibly a stupid question sorry in advance. I'm very new to this and trying to automate a big task at work

Comment: @austin Edit your question with exactly what you are trying, and we'll see if if we can't figure out what isn't working correctly.

Comment: @tgikal thank you, my question is up-to-date. C:\Users\austin.shanahan\Desktop\PeopleTest\S\SE-SH\Shanahan,Austin-1234 - this is the output i would be looking for. S and SE-SH are the two in-between subdirs. However, I need my code to search through them automatically. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @austin you still have `for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):` instead of `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start):`, sorry about that, was a late edit on my part, managed to catch the code in that minute I had it like that.